# How do i stringify and then parse back arrays of images?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a game which has a canvas where images are randomly generated and stored into an array. I want the user to be able to save their progress. So far only they text such as the day the player is on and gold the player has are able to save and reload. I would like the images on the canvas to be able to save as well.

```
player = {
    day: 1,
    gold: 1000,
    health: 100,
    hunger: 100,
    happy: 60,
    shop: [],
    shopItem: [], //the name of player.shop item
    shopPrice: [], //the price of player.shop item
    shopNumber: [], //the quantity of player.shop item
    shopStoreDate: [], //the store date of player.shop item
    storage: [], //the name of player.storage item
    storageNumber: [], //the quantity of player.storage item
    storageDay: [], //the store date of player.storage item
    storageImage: [], //the image of player.storage item
    feed: [],
};

function newGame() {
    player = {};
};

function reload() {
    player = {
        day: 1,
        gold: 1000,
        health: 100,
        hunger: 100,
        happy: 60,
        shop: [],
        shopItem: [], //the name of player.shop item
        shopPrice: [], //the price of player.shop item
        shopNumber: [], //the quantity of player.shop item
        shopStoreDate: [], //the store date of player.shop item
        storage: [], //the name of player.storage item
        storageNumber: [], //the quantity of player.storage item
        storageDay: [], //the store date of player.storage item
        storageImage: [], //the image of player.storage item
        feed: [],
    }

    $("#day").text("Day " + player.day);
    $("#gold").text("Gold: " + player.gold);

};
```

images are drawn

```
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[0], box01_x + 10, box01_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[1], box02_x + 10, box02_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[2], box03_x + 10, box03_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[3], box04_x + 10, box04_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[4], box05_x + 10, box05_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
ctx.drawImage(player.shop[5], box06_x + 10, box06_y + 10, food_width, food_height);
```

here the items in the store are randomly generated

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var rand = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);       //0-99

    if (rand<13) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage1; 
    } else if (rand<26) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage2;
    } else if (rand<39) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage3;
    } else if (rand<52) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage4;
    } else if (rand<59) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage5;
    } else if (rand<66) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage6;
    } else if (rand<73) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage7;
    } else if (rand<80) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage8;
    } else if (rand<87) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage9;
    } else if (rand<94) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage10;
    } else if (rand<96) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage11;
    } else if (rand<98) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage12;
    } else if (rand<100) {
        player.shop[i] = foodImage13;
    }
}
```

I am able to get the day number and gold that was on the page before but the images will not redraw

```
 `function save() {
    var save = {
        player1 : player,
    }

    localStorage.setItem("save", JSON.stringify(save));
};

function load() {

    var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
    if(savegame != null && savegame != undefined){
        player = savegame.player1;
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('shopCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');  

    $("#day").text("Day " + player.day); //this works
    $("#gold").text("Gold: " + player.gold); // this works
    ctx.drawImage(player.shop[0],70,40,100,100); // this doesn't work   

};`
```

here is my game http://students.bcitdev.com/A00999050/HungryPets5/MonsterCollection.html

here is my stack overflow. The code is the exact same as the link above but it does not work in stack overflow for some reason https://jsfiddle.net/693xLyqp/2/

Comment: Could you add the HTML you are using? Or, better yet, add a jsfiddle or equivalent?

Comment: http://students.bcitdev.com/A00999050/HungryPets5/MonsterCollection.html   This is how the game works as of now                                       this is the fiddle with the same code as the link above but it doesnt work correctly https://jsfiddle.net/693xLyqp/2/ @sven